# Select from 6 tables get one result only

Tags: php, join, mysqli

I have about 6 tables and I am while looping on them the results comes 1 result it should be more

see my code here

```
$institute = $_POST['institute'];
$sections = $_POST['sections'];
$division = $_POST['division'];


$getSearch = $db->prepare("SELECT
a.name, a.phase, a.setNumber, a.email, a.sudImage, a.activity, a.id AS stud_id,
b.id, b.ins_name,
c.id, c.sec_name,
d.id, d.div_name,
e.id, e.std_id, e.sub_id, e.absence,
f.id, f.sub_name, f.subHour, f.level
FROM student_basic_info AS a
JOIN institutes AS b ON (a.institute = b.id)
CROSS JOIN ins_sections AS c ON (a.section = c.id)
CROSS JOIN ins_division AS d ON (a.division = d.id)
CROSS JOIN student_absence AS e ON (a.id = e.std_id)
CROSS JOIN ins_subjects AS f ON (e.sub_id = f.id)
WHERE a.institute =? AND a.section = ? AND a.division =?
GROUP BY a.id
");

$studSearch = array();
$getSearch->bind_param('iii', $institute, $sections, $division);
if ($getSearch->execute()) {
    $results = $getSearch->get_result();
    while ($vStud = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
        $studSearch[] = $vStud;
        var_dump($studSearch);
        ?>
```

the var_dump

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=17)
      'name' => string 'الدفع النقدي' (length=23)
      'phase' => string 'ابتدائي' (length=14)
      'setNumber' => int 0
      'email' => string 'johnef' (length=6)
      'sudImage' => string '' (length=0)
      'activity' => int 0
      'stud_id' => int 7
      'id' => int 3
      'ins_name' => string 'معهد الفنون' (length=21)
      'sec_name' => string 'فنون مسرح' (length=17)
      'div_name' => string 'شعبة مرجانية 10' (length=26)
      'std_id' => int 7
      'sub_id' => int 3
      'absence' => string '' (length=0)
      'sub_name' => string 'فنون تطبيقية' (length=23)
      'subHour' => string '2' (length=1)
      'level' => string 'المستوي الأول' (length=25)
```

**EDIT**

```
SELECT a.name, a.phase, a.setNumber, a.email, a.sudImage, a.activity, 
      a.id AS stud_id, b.id, b.ins_name, c.id, c.sec_name, d.id, d.div_name,
      e.id, e.std_id, e.sub_id, e.absence, f.id, f.sub_name, f.subHour, f.level 
FROM student_basic_info AS a 
  JOIN institutes AS b ON (a.institute = b.id)
  CROSS JOIN ins_sections AS c ON (a.section = c.id) 
  CROSS JOIN ins_division AS d ON (a.division = d.id) 
  CROSS JOIN student_absence AS e ON (a.id = e.std_id) 
  CROSS JOIN ins_subjects AS f ON (e.sub_id = f.id) 
WHERE a.institute =1 AND a.section = 1 AND a.division =7 
GROUP BY a.id
```

and yes I got the same results (1) record cam out which it should be at last (6) or (7) of records

Comment: Your code is wide open for sql injection

Comment: @SuperDJ Can you explain? I think OP is using `prepare` and `bind_param` the right way.

Comment: Yes please explain how to fix?

Comment: Eventough you're using prepare. I Would still advice to use `$db->real_escape_string` just to be sure

Comment: Which results do you expect then? Can you add some table data to your question?

Comment: Can you confirm that if you run the complete query in a gui ( heidi for instance ) with the values supplied where you have the placeholders that you actually get more than 1 record?

Comment: @SuperDJ You **should not** use `real_escape_string` with `bind_param`: check this [PHP guide](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), especially the "Escaping and SQL injection" section.

Comment: @Passerby It's not saying not to use it. It says it is not necessary. Or atleast thats the way I interperet it.

Comment: Yes just moment I am running the query on the phpMyAdmin

Comment: Query must be taking a long time to run '-)

Comment: @RamRaider I try the same query on phpMyAdmin but I got no results (MySQL returned an empty result)

Comment: You did substitute the actual values into the query rather than running with the `?` placeholders didn't you?

Comment: No I replaced ? with values.

Comment: Can you add, to your oginal question, the resolved sql that you actually tried running in `phpMyAdmin` so we can see ?